# How to properly create and render functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to create and render a functional component using [the instructions here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) as a base.  From what I've sen in there I should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <OtherComponent props="test" />
       </div>
   )}
   function OtherComponent(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    );
   }
}
```

But this throws the error:

```
Unexpected token:    function OtherComponent(props) {
                          ^
```

I found a few posts that suggested removing the `function` so I tried that but then it throws the error:

```
OtherComponent is not defined
```

I'm able to get it working by creating a separate class component like so:

```
class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
```

But that's not what I want to do.  What is the proper way to create/render a functional component in React.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example this one works. See the docs ;)
[React - Composing Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components)

```
function OtherComponent(props) {
  return <div>test</div>;
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <OtherComponent props="test" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  OtherComponent = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        test
      </div>
    );
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {this.OtherComponent("test")}
       </div>
   )}

}
```

Comment: Still throws the `OtherComponent is not defined` error

Comment: This also works for me, but you should only do it if you want to nest your components like <Table.Row> for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a component inside of another component. A functional component means that the component is created from a function and is not a class. It can't have it's own state, because the state is initialized in class constructor. Check out this article for more info https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

```
const otherComponent = (props) =>
  <div>
    test
  </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. Its not correct to declare a component in a render function. If it is used solely in a parent component why not make that explicit and use static

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static myOtherComponent = (props) => <div>{'test'}</div>

render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <MyComponent.myOtherComponent  {props} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

The myOtherComponent  behaviour is controlled purely through the props it gets , it won't have its own state.

Or you could just make it a separate component e.g

```
export default myOtherComponent  = (props) => ()
```

and import it into MyComponent. Please note , now with hooks ( see React Docs ),  you can use hooks to mimic state etc in functional components and the latter approach might be your cleanest and most flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can define a function component

```
function OtherComponent(props) {
  return <div>{props}</div>;
}
```

And now you can use functional component in your App (class component) like below

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <OtherComponent props="test" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```